# Why does the mui datepicker onChange method revert the format of the date back to the default format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-fns

I am using material ui's date picker.

https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#basic-usage

The default format of the datepicker is `MM-dd-yyyy` (02-23-2022). I want to change the default format to be dd-MM-yyyy` eg. (23-02-2022).

To have it display in the correct format i have used the `inputFormat`. However i noticed that the onChange value is still an object and therefore i have used the `format` function from the adapter date-fns to format the value before storing it in state.

However, although the console logs the correct foramt, the value being set in state for the date is still using the old format (MM-dd-yyyy)

What am i doing wrong here. Please see the ccodesandbox for continence  https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-460hxz?file=/demo.js:418-820

```
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          label="Basic example"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(format(newValue, "dd-MM-yyyy"));
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          mask="__-__-____"
          inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a 'rifmFormatter' prop, and write a function to handle it. I am working on MUI X, but it is the same as in previous versions. see: https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to apply any format for the data. `inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"` will take care of everything on MUI Datepicker. This code is working perfectly. Whatever value you are getting is basically a `Date` type. You can apply format on that.

```
<DatePicker
  views={["day"]}
  label="Just date"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />}
/>;
```

Attaching the sandbox for reference.

[image: Edit ViewsDatePicker Material Demo (forked)]

Answer (score -2):

Use format

```
<DatePicker 
        views={["year", "month", "day"]}
        slotProps={{ textField: { placeholder: 'DD/MM/YYYY', name: props.name } }}
        {...props}
        label=""
        value={value ? dayjs(props.selected) : value}
        format="DD-MM-YYYY"
      />
```